# Derived stack 2-perfect complexes and derived equivalences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$. Toën and Vaquié construct the derived stack of perfect complexes on $X$, which I will denote $\mathcal{DP}er(X)$. They prove that this derived stack naturally comes equipped with a sheaf of DG-algebras (a replacement of the tangent sheaf of a scheme) and that for all $F$, perfect complex on $X$, we have:

$$T_{\mathcal{DP}er(X),F} = \mathrm{RHom}_X(F,F)[1].$$

Using this, it is easy to show that if $\Phi : D^{perf}(X) \longrightarrow D^{perf}(Y)$ is an equivalence between the DG category of perfect complexes on $X$ and that of $Y$, then $\Phi$ induces an ismorphism of derived stacks:

$$\Phi : \mathcal{DP}er(X) \simeq \mathcal{DP}er(Y).$$

**Vague Question**: Is it possible to extend all of this story in the world of vector $2$-bundles?

**Slightly more precise question 1** : I heard that there is a notion of vector $2$-bundle (introduced by Kapranov-Vovoedsky, Baer-Cranz and others). Furthermore, it seems that Urs Schreiber is claiming on *nLab* that the "moduli space" of degree $0$ line $2$-bundles is the intermediate Jacobian of level $2$ (I guess à la Weil) : see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/line+2-bundle).

I was wondering if there was a way to give a rigorous construction of the moduli space of degree $0$ line $2$-bundles? If so, is there a way to construct a *derived stack of perfect $2$-complexes* on $X$?

**Slightly more precise question 2**: Let $ \Phi : D^{perf}(X) \longrightarrow D^{perf}(Y)$ be an equivalence between the DG-category of perfect complexes on $X$ and that of $Y$. Are there some non-trivial conditions on $\Phi$ which would guarantee that $\Phi$ lifts to an equivalence between the $??$-DG categories of perfect $2$-complexes on $X$ and $Y$? (By non trivial, I mean conditions which do not look like "$\Phi$ comes from an algebraic isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$").

*Warning* : I am close to be a complete beginner on derived algebraic geometry, so please do not hesitate to point out if some parts of my question do not make any sense!

Comment: Maybe a "line $2$-bundle" is the same as $\mathbb{G}_m$-gerbe.  There is work of Brylinski and others connecting this to Deligne cohomology, which in turn connects to the (Griffiths) intermediate Jacobian.  Perhaps "vector $2$-bundle" is then a $\textbf{GL}_n$-gerbe for some integer $n\geq 1$.

Comment: One natural candidate for your "perfect 2-complexes" are quasicoherent sheaves of categories (or "quasicoherent stacks"), which are indeed a derived analog of 2-vector bundles. There are very thorough studies of these by Gaitsgory ("Sheaves of Categories and a notion of 1-affineness") and Lurie (Chapter 10 of Spectral Algebraic Geometry), available on their respective web pages.

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi : Thanks a lot for the reference! Could I dare to ask you if they study/define $??$-derived stacks of such objects?

Comment: That sounds tricky. First these are not dg categories but more "nonlinear" objects. Second, unlike say perfect complexes just parametrizing such beasts over a point (i.e. parametrizing all dg categories) already seems daunting. What's much nicer is as Jason suggests parametrizing objects that are locally trivial (gerbes), whose moduli stacks are easy to construct (as mapping spaces to some classifying space).

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi : Your last sentence is very interesting to me. Do you know a reference where the moduli stacks of "gerbes" is constructed/studied? Thanks a lot.